# Div's content editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea, edit

I have this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#k123").click(function () {
                //var text=$(this).val(); //this does not work
                var text=$(this).text();
                var k='<div id="k123"><textarea rows="10" cols="10">' + text + '</textarea><br /><input     type="button" onclick="save();" value="save"><input type="button" onclick="cancel();"     value="cancel"></div>';
                $(this).replaceWith(k);
            });

        }); 

        function save() {
        }
        function cancel() {
            //alert(text);
            var k='<div id="k123"></div>';
            $("#k123").replaceWith(k);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="k123">aaaaa</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is :

1)In  both functions : cancel &  save , How can I get content of div id->#k123->textarea->content
functions cancel & save are outside the scope and they are independent functions I cannot tell $(this).parent().

I need to ask about div which has id #k123 , then get inside to textarea's content and get it.
and I have also to get id #k123 automatically because if I have many divs I cannot tell save & cancel manually the div's id, cancel & save should know the div's id sender from the input type='button'`s parent id.

****please I do not prefer the suggestion of sending div id from input button**

****We are assuming that both input buttons have no IDS or Names**

I tried another way but still having same problem
I replaced

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#k123").click(function () {
var text=$(this).text();
var k='<div id="k123"><textarea rows="10" cols="10">' + text + '</textarea><br /><input     type="button" value="save"><input type="button" value="cancel"></div>';
$(this).replaceWith(k);
});

//$("#k123 > input").click(function() {
$("#k123").children("input:second").click(function() {
alert("hi");
});

});
```

thank you.

Comment: Why cannot you use `$(this).parent()`? Since `save()` and `cancel()` are fired by onlick attribute `$(this)` would be the `input` element which fired the function. `$(this).parents('div')` will give you first parent `div` element.

Comment: Seems like his $("#k123").click() just takes the div contents and wraps it with a textform...not sure what the point is

Comment: @Zefiryn and if I want to get the textarea's content would it be like this ?

$(this).parents("div").children("textarea").text();

Comment: Or `$(this).siblings('textarea').val()` if you will have only one `textarea` at the same level

Comment: @Zefiryn I tried it , it gives me undefined :S

Comment: Right, I forgot that you need to pass the element in onclick attribute, so in this case it should be `onclick="save(this);"` and `onclick="cancel(this);"`. The `save()` and `cancel()` function in this case should be changed to `save(input)` and `cancel(input)`. Inside those function input would be the calling element. So you could do `$(input).siblings('textarea').val();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the working code for you below.  You don't even need an id.. just a container div and delegation of events.  The below accomplishes what I thought you were after, in what I believe to be a much simpler, and much more efficient fashion:

(I've added comments to assist in understanding the code)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container").on('click', function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).is('input') && !$(e.target).is('textarea')) { //check to make sure the target is neither an input or a textarea
            var div_text = $(e.target).text(); // use a variable named something other than text, because text is already a method for another element
            $(e.target).data('text',div_text); // set the div's current contents as a hidden data attribute, to be retrieved later.  You can get rid of this and the other line if you want cancel to completely wipe the div.
            var k = '<textarea rows="10" cols="10">' + div_text + '</textarea><br /><input type="button" value="save"><input type="button" value="cancel">';
            $(e.target).html(k); //set the inner HTML of the div, so we don't lose any data saved to that div
        }
        if ($(e.target).is('input') && $(e.target).val() == 'save') {
            $(e.target).parent().html($(e.target).parent().find('textarea').val()); // replace the current contents of the parent div with the contents of the textarea within it.

        } else if ($(e.target).is('input') && $(e.target).val() == 'cancel') {
            $(e.target).parent().html($(e.target).parent().data('text')); //set the contents to the old contents, as stored in the data attribute.  Just replace the contents of the .html() here with '' to completely clear it.
        }
    });
});​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/25Hay/2)

Comment: As a note, you need to delegate events in order to bind to dynamically created elements, which is why VI's answer didn't work.

Comment: I tried something else above,, could u please check why's it working.?

Comment: @eawedat I don't understand why you don't accept this answer.  It has working code.  Your code is not working because the element is created dynamically, and thus the click event is not bound to it.

Comment: for sure I accept your answer and I thank you much. but I wanted to understand my mine is not working..so as you're saying if I want to make mine working I should use .bind('click ?

Comment: @eawedat Not `.bind()`, `.on()`.  That method is up-to-date.  To delegate elements, it should be [`$(container).on('space-delimited event list', 'selectors for targeted elements', function() { // do stuff });`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

**REVISED - WORKS**

Check this out... not quite there but close!

[REVISED JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/Wx3Sb/)

```
function editit() {

        var divId = $(this).attr('id');

        var text = $(this).html();

        var k = '<div id="' + divId + '" class="editable"><textarea id="newvalue' + divId +'" rows="10" cols="10">' + text + '</textarea><br /><input id="save'  + divId + '" type="button" value="save"><input id="cancel'  + divId + '" type="button" value="cancel"></div>';

        $('#' + divId).replaceWith(k);

        $('#cancel' + divId).click(function() {
            $('#' + divId).replaceWith('<div id="' + divId + '" class="editable">' + text + '</div>');
            $('.editable').bind('click', editit);
        });

        $('#save' + divId).click(function() {
            $('#' + divId).replaceWith('<div id="' + divId + '" class="editable">' + $("#newvalue" + divId).val()+ '</div>');
            $('.editable').bind('click', editit);
        });

    }

 $('.editable').bind('click', editit);
```

Comment: The question is more verbose than that.  This answer won't cut it.

Comment: @VIDesignz but I need to know how to get the div's id inside function cancel and function save

Comment: @VIDesignz works for 1st time. does not let u edit for second time

Comment: @eawedat See my answer for a working solution that works multiple times.